# Meteor Accounts - Login forms change HTML remove dropdown JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I modify Meteor's Accounts-ui to change the classes and the html tags rendered without re-writing all the accounts-ui logic? 
For example I'd like to remove the "[dropdown](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dropdown.js)" behavior and just display the form directly in my page. 
I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025621/how-to-style-meteor-js-loginbuttons/15034053) but it doesn't go into detail - it just removes the default CSS. I'd like to go a bit deeper..

Comment: Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621384/meteorjs-login-buttons-without-a-dropdown/14627328#14627328

Comment: I did, didn't help. I believe it's a bit outdated. Plus he's doing github auth, I want to do local..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Styling**

Remove `accounts-ui`

```
meteor remove accounts-ui
```

Add `accounts-ui-unstyled` & `less`

```
meteor add accounts-ui-unstyled
meteor add less
```

Finally, add the following file to your project directory & edit it to your viewing pleasure

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui/login_buttons.less

**More customization**

You can edit the accounts-ui package and edit html & js without starting from scratch:

Remove the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package and add the stuff in the dir below (except package.js & accounts_ui_tests.js) to your project's `client` dir, add `accounts-urls` and edit it to fine tune it to your spec.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled

**Until meteor gives us a way to specify load order**

Rename the following files so they load in the correct order

```
1accounts_ui.js
2login_buttons.html
3login_buttons_single.html
4login_buttons_dropdown.html
5login_buttons_dialogs.html
6login_buttons_session.js
7login_buttons.js
8login_buttons_single.js
9login_buttons_dropdown.js
login_buttons_dialogs.js
```

Comment: Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at Object.Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.dropdownVisible

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined login_buttons_dialogs.js:73
Template._resetPasswordDialog.inResetPasswordFlow

Comment: Looks like the dev team really has to sort out loading order for you :P check the update, if you rename the files it should work

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor that says how to build things from scratch..

Comment: You don't really have to do it from scratch, I just tried the above it works fine, also in deployment mode all the files are converged into one so the dirty numbering doesn't reach the user

Comment: its working (no errors) but boy.. I need minimum a week to figure out how to modify that thing. Lots of code I don't need...

Comment: Ok its starting to make sense now.. I think once I finish this one I should commit it to github or somewhere could help lots of folks

Comment: I also opened a request on github to find a nicer way to name the files I'm on my phone so it's hard to post the link, it at the meteor github repo if you had nicer names than load in order maybe we could get it changed

Answer (score 7):

I figured this out for another answer, but thought I'd put it in here since it seems like a quicker way to get what you want.

```
Template.login.rendered = function()
{
    Accounts._loginButtonsSession.set('dropdownVisible', true);
};
```

(Template.login should be Template.*yourTemplateWithLoginButtons*)

Comment: Nice! Quick and Dirty!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is remove the drop down behavior, then it would suffice to just add the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package and hide the components you don't want visible: e.g.:

```css
.login-link-text { display: none; }
```

in your CSS to hide the *Sign in* link.

Here are the relevant id's and classes that you look into styling:

```css
#forgot-password-link
#login-buttons
#login-buttons-password
#login-dropdown-list
#login-email
#login-email-label
#login-email-label-and-input
#login-password
#login-password-label
#login-password-label-and-input
#login-sign-in-link
#signup-link
.accounts-dialog
.additional-link
.additional-link-container
.login-button
.login-button-form-submit
.login-buttons-dropdown-align-left
.login-close-text-clear
.login-close-textClose
.login-form
.login-form-sign-in
.login-link-and-dropdown-list
.login-link-text
.login-password-form
```

Comment: This isn't really helpful to change the dropdown behavior as both the styled and unstyled ui packages dynamically add the dropdown's data rather than just showing and hiding at the opportune moments.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `html` template similar to this below. Style it to your taste.

`meteor add accounts-password accounts-ui`

```
                <template name="login">
                     <form class="login-form">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3>Login</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </template>
```

You can now call `Meteor.loginWithPassword` in the template event like so:

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit .login-form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = e.target.email.value;
        var password = e.target.password.value;
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password,function(error){
            if(error) {
                //do something if error occurred or 
            }else{
               FlowRouter.go('/');
            }
        });
     }
 });
```

You can create another form for registration as well.

Just call `Accounts.createUser(object, callback);`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit coming late but might help.

Create your own `html` template similar to this below. Style it to your taste.

`meteor add accounts-password accounts-ui`

```
                <template name="login">
                     <form class="login-form">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3>Login</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </template>
```

You can now call `Meteor.loginWithPassword` in the template event like so:

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit .login-form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = e.target.email.value;
        var password = e.target.password.value;
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password,function(error){
            if(error) {
                //do something if error occurred or 
            }else{
               FlowRouter.go('/');
            }
        });
     }
 });
```

You can create another form for registration as well.

Just call `Accounts.createUser(object, callback);`